# Can we implement GraphQL in Play Framework in Java

Tags: java, playframework, graphql

Can we implement GraphQL in Play Framework in Java?

I have an existing API using Play and we want to migrate it to Realm, and we want to use GraphQL for us to write/read in the Object Server.

How to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this list: [awesome-graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/awesome-graphql-java), you can probably use one of those libraries to implement an endpoint on your existing server and use GraphQL next to it! I don't have any experience with the play framework, but if you can use it in Spark Java it can be done in your framework of choice

Comment: Have you tried GraphQL-Java? https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java

Comment: Can anyone share their experience of migrating from REST in Play Framework Java to GraphQL?